# Tensorflow Simple Audio Recognition Error on Freeze.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, audio, speech-recognition

I've been following [the tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition) on how to make a Simple Audio Recognition.

First I encountered an error when I entered

```
python tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/freeze.py
```

saying

> python: can't open file 'tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/freeze.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

So I just went to the directory of tensorflow then drag the file in cmd... but then I encountered another error saying:

> "tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: FindFirstFile failed for: ./config/systemprofile/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/INetCache/Content.IE5 : Access is denied.
>   ; Input/output error"

I'm running it as administrator as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq8Qy.jpg). How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you get the same results when you run it from local directory (speech_commands), not from c:/windows/system32 folder? The error seems to refer to Temporary folder Content.IE5 which by default is restricted to everybody.

Comment: what do you mean? when i don't run it in admin? I get a different error when i don't run it in administrator..
`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: FindFirstFile failed for: ./AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary Internet Files : Access is denied.
; Input/output error`

Comment: Based on your screenshot you are executing the command from c:/windows/system32 folder, but script is located in a different directory, what I am asking is what happens when you run the script once your path is the same as where the script is located, in this case: tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/

Comment: I did what you asked me to do, but it gave me a different error... here's the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka4Xl.jpg

I think its because I'm supposed to enter 
`python tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/freeze.py \
--start_checkpoint=/tmp/speech_commands_train/conv.ckpt-18000 \
--output_file=/tmp/my_frozen_graph.pb`
It's what the tutorial is telling me to do https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrIYL.jpg

But when i enter those code I get this error here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwXLC.jpg

Comment: sorry I'm noob.. haha.. and thank you for giving your time to answer my question..

Comment: You are copying and pasting the command, which normally causes an error, please make sure when you copy and paste it actually runs all the command in the same line. Since the example is for Unix you see a /tmp/ directory, make sure you convert it to a valid Windows directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working, all i had to do was to run the command line in the TensorFlow source like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXtHl.jpg)